# conditionally calculate the sum of combination of columns from a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, combinations

I have the existing dataframe `df` as shown below for a few rows:

```
dput(df[c(1,100,200,300,400,500,600),])
structure(list(ext.left = c(0.483354599644366, 0.490770631112789, 
0.568556150678021, 0.477080531848485, 0.478788576652198, 0.540322404211098, 
0.735991659632199), N_l = c(1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3), N_b = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), A = c(-12, -12, -12, -15, -15, -9, -9), x.sqr = c(1440, 
1440, 1440, 2250, 2250, 810, 810), e_1 = c(21.8, 21.8, 21.8, 
29, 29, 14.6, 14.6), e_2 = c(0, 9.8, 9.8, 17, 17, 2.6, 2.6), 
e_3 = c(0, -2.2, -2.2, 5, 5, 0, -9.4), e_4 = c(0, -14.2, 
-14.2, -7, -7, 0, 0), e_5 = c(0, 0, 0, -19, -19, 0, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 
100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L), class = "data.frame")

Multi.Presence <- data.frame(N_l = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))
Multi.Presence$m <- ifelse(Multi.Presence$N_l >= 4, 0.65,NA)
Multi.Presence$m[1:3] <- c(1.2, 1, 0.85)
```

I am using the function below:

```
R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l <- x["N_l"]
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr <- x["x.sqr"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  f <- max(Multi.Presence$m[N_l] * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(e,N_l,sum) / x.sqr)))
  return(max(f))
}

DF <- cbind(df, vars = (apply(df, 1, R)))
```

Some of the terms in the columns defined as `e` in the function `R` are zero. When I use the `combn(e,N_l,sum)` it grabs the value of e that is zero when `A` is negative to get the maximum value of `f`. But I was the function to still find the maximum value of `f` but do not consider the zero terms in `e` when calculating `combn(e,N_l,sum)`.

Comment: @akrun just updated!

Comment: In the function, do you need `e1 <- e[e != 0]; f <- max(Multi.Presence$m[N_l] * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(e1,N_l,sum) / x.sqr))); max(f)`